# How can we have numerical rather than string items in flutter dropdown

Tags: flutter

is there a way to have a dropdown with numerical values? I observed many representing 1 as '1' or 'one' in their items list. How can we do it in Flutter?

Answer (score 1):

**Do this :**

first define :

```
var list = [
    "1", //or "one"
    "2",
    "3",
    "4",
    "4",
    "5",
    "6",
    "7",
    "8",
    "9",
    "10",
    "11"
  ];

String defaultList;
```

Then use this in your widget:

```
  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      DropdownButton<String>(
                        items: list.map((String value) {
                          return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                            value: value,
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text(
                                value,
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        }).toList(),
                        value: defaultList,
                        onChanged: (String value) {
                          setState(() {
                            defaultList = value;
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
```

Comment: string - value mapping in the dropdown resolved my confusion. Thanks.

Comment: If this answer did helpful for you, please vote and set right green tick, to other people use it.